# Show password button on entry in gtk

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

Is there a way in gtk to make an eye icon on the right of an entry to show a password? I know there is a way to make a checkbox under an entry to show the password, but I want the button to be inside the entry, not outside. To put it simply:

What i'm looking for is this:
[show password icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxzMm.jpg)

...and not this: [show password checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6opgY.png)

(I'm sorry that I cant embed the image. The site says I need 10 reputation first. I actually used to have almost 300 untill I got banned from a dislike attack. Please think before you dislike because it literally only takes ~20 to permenantly ban a year-long user. If anyone has enough reputation to edit the question and add the images in, please do)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put an icon to Gtk.Entry with the `set_icon_from_` functions, for example [`set_icon_from_name`](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/method.Entry.set_icon_from_icon_name.html).

So you need to set the icon to for example to the `view-reveal-symbolic.symbolic` icon, make it clickable with [`set_icon_activatable`](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/method.Entry.set_icon_activatable.html) and then in the signal handler for the [`icon-press`](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/signal.Entry.icon-press.html) event you need to [set_visibility](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/method.Entry.set_visibility.html) to either hide or show the text (and also change the icon to something like `view-conceal-symbolic.symbolic`).

So the Gtk.Entry code could look like this

```c
GtkWidget *entry = gtk_entry_new();
gtk_entry_set_visibility(GTK_ENTRY(entry), FALSE);
gtk_entry_set_icon_from_icon_name(GTK_ENTRY(entry), 
                                  GTK_ENTRY_ICON_SECONDARY, 
                                  "view-reveal-symbolic.symbolic");
gtk_entry_set_icon_activatable(GTK_ENTRY(entry), GTK_ENTRY_ICON_SECONDARY, TRUE);
g_signal_connect(entry, "icon-press", G_CALLBACK (on_icon_press), NULL);
```

and the signal handler

```c
void on_icon_press(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data) {   
    gboolean visible = gtk_entry_get_visibility(GTK_ENTRY(widget));
    
    if (visible) {
        gtk_entry_set_visibility(GTK_ENTRY(widget), FALSE);
        gtk_entry_set_icon_from_icon_name(GTK_ENTRY(widget), 
                                          GTK_ENTRY_ICON_SECONDARY, 
                                          "view-reveal-symbolic.symbolic");
    } else {
        gtk_entry_set_visibility(GTK_ENTRY(widget), TRUE);
        gtk_entry_set_icon_from_icon_name(GTK_ENTRY(widget), 
                                          GTK_ENTRY_ICON_SECONDARY, 
                                          "view-conceal-symbolic.symbolic");
    }
}
```

And you'll get something like this:

[image] [image]

Comment: Great answer, thank you! You can also use `visibility` and `image-red-eye` icons if you like them more.